# iText7: Error at file pointer when merging two pdfs

Tags: itext, itext7

We are in the last steps of evaluating iText7. We use iText 7.1.0 and html2pdf 2.0.0.

What we do: we send a json_encoded collection with pdf-data (which includes html for header, body and footer) to our Java app. There we iterate over the collection, create a byteArrayOutputStream for each pdf-data element and merge them together. We then send the results to a script which echoes it to e.g. a browser. Although the pdf is displayed correctly, we encounter errors while creating it:

```
    com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 226,416.
    ...
    Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: xref subsection not found.
    ... 73 common frames omitted
```

If we create only one part of the collection, no error is thrown.

Iterate over collection and merge:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public byte[] index(@RequestBody PDFDataModelCollection elements, Model model) throws IOException {    
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
    try (PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(writer)) {
        for (PDFDataModel pdfDataModel : elements.getElements()) {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(creationService.createDatasheet(pdfDataModel)));
            try (PdfDocument sourceDoc = new PdfDocument(reader)) {
                int n = sourceDoc.getNumberOfPages(); //<-- IOException on second iteration
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                    PdfPage page = sourceDoc.getPage(i).copyTo(resultDoc);
                    resultDoc.addPage(page);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(); //outputs the final pdf
}
```

Creation of part:

```
public byte[] createDatasheet(PDFDataModel pdfDataModel) throws IOException {
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);

    //Initialize PDF document
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);

    try (
        Document document = new Document(pdfDoc)
    ) {

        //header, footer, etc

        //body
        for (IElement element : HtmlConverter.convertToElements(pdfDataModel.getBody(), this.props)) {
            document.add((IBlockElement) element);
        }

        footer.writeTotalNumberOnPages(pdfDoc);
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
}
```

We are grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `createDatasheet` you appear to re-use some `byteArrayOutputStream` without clearing it first.

In the first iteration, therefore, everything works as desired, at the end of `createDatasheet` you have a single PDF file in it.

In the second iteration, though, you have two PDF files in that `byteArrayOutputStream`, one after the other. This concatenation does not form a valid single PDF.

Thus, `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` returns something broken.

To fix this, either make the `byteArrayOutputStream` local to `createDatasheet` and create a new instance every time or alternatively reset `byteArrayOutputStream` at the start of `createDatasheet`:

```
public byte[] createDatasheet(PDFDataModel pdfDataModel) throws IOException {
    byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(byteArrayOutputStream);
    [...]
```